# Ethernet cables types for gaming

Tags: ethernet, internet-connection, raw-ethernet

Which cables are best for gaming, cat5 e or cat7? I have top tier internet connection. So im just looking for latency to the minimum

Comment: Voting to close as cable recommendations for gaming have nothing to do with programming. This is unlikely to be ontopic on any SE site unfortunately.

Comment: @Carcigenicate 
so, where should we post hardware questions? I have a question about a Lan card, and I also posted it here, and it got downvoted. I wanted to find a corresponding forum, but this one was the best variant for my problem. 
 I am not arguing, I am asking for help.

Comment: @SergeyLarin Super User, another site in the network, is for computer problems. Most sites here are for objective problems though, not suggestions. Reddit probably has a computer hardware subreddit for things like this.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the cable is working correctly it has zero impact* on whatever workload you put on it. Gigabit is as fine over Cat.5e as over Cat.6 or Cat.7 or Cat.8.

*Not true with absolute precision: Cat.7 has a velocity factor (VF) of .79, so with a 100 m cable run it would actually save you 90 nanoseconds in comparison to Cat.5e (VF .66) each direction - or 9 ns for a 10 m cable. You might well round that off to zero though.